# "Safe" way to add an element to a std::vector beyond its size() but under its capacity()

Tags: c++, vector, size, capacity

It might sound dangerous, but I'm trying to do something like this:

```
std::vector<StructureSlowToBeCreated> vElems;

StructureSlowToBeCreated s1, s2;

vElems.reserve(many_slots_for_structs);

vElems[x1] = s1; // I can ensure x1, x2 < many_slots_for_structs
vElems[x2] = s2;
```

Basically, the idea is to avoid using

```
vElems.resize(many_slots_for_structs);
```

Since both **s1** and **s2** are slow to be created, hence I don't want to do it twice. As I said, I can 100% ensure **x1** and **x2** are going to be within the vector *capacity* boundaries, but also many times certainly outside the *size* boundaries (ergo, using *"at()"* would end up in an exception).

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Or should I consider this one clean enough (I've the feeling it isn't).

And I really need to place **s1** at the **x1** index, otherwise, I'd need to store **x1** as a parameter of **s1** and store a secondary map to link **x1** with the position of **s1** in the vector (and I'd add the cost of looking the map on each access to **s1** or **s2**, something I'd like to avoid at all cost).

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I think there are plenty of examples and references on how to use vectors out there. And yes, there's a cleaner way, because your way is a bug.

Comment: What about using `reserve` and `push_back` or `emplace_back`?

Comment: Either use `emplace_back` so you avoid pointless construction, fix your class so it's not so slow to construct, or use a `std::vector<std::optional<X>>` (or `boost::optional`) to lazily construct the actual elements.

Comment: Or use a map, or similar container.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Good point, I missed the bit about how these need to be at specific indices. Sounds like "hey my container doesn't support this" is probably a good indicator you're using the wrong one.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. A cleaner way to do... _what_? What is the problem exactly with simply adding these objects to your vector? With an up-front `reserve`, they won't ever need to be copied or moved elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access a std::vector above its size. It may seem to work, but [it is UB](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) and it will generate problems at the end.

The normal way to perform this task would be to use a map, so that you only create the elements you need. However, finding the n-th element is O(logn) instead of constant time for the std::vector.

```
std::map<size_t, StructureSlowToBeCreated> myMap;
```

If you really need constant time access, you have to resize the vector. I understand that you do not want to default-construct all the elements because it is a time-consuming operation. Then, you can create an std::vector of other elements that store your object. For example:

```
std::vector<std::optional<StrSlowToBeCreated>> myVec; // as suggested by GManNickG
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<StructureSlowToBeCreated>> myVec;
```

Probably, you can choose between optional and unique_ptr depending of the object size.

Comment: Thanks, the idea of using the std::optional looks elegant and neat.

Comment: Yes, it is. The problem with optional is that you need either C++17 or boost. Also, the size of an optional is greater than the size of the object it contains. Using unique_ptr is a bit more complicated, but you only need C++11 and the size of unique_ptr is only the size of a pointer.